# DllImport from c# project to c++ project in same solution

Tags: c#, c++

I have a solution with two projects:

- C# console application (.NET Core 3.1)
- and C++ Dynamic Library (.dll)

I need to call the C++ DLL from the C# project, using `DllImport`. When I provide the full path of the DLL, the application finds it. But I want to replace the path with a relative path, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: dll need to be in the same folder as the c# application.  Normally I use Add Existing Item : Browse to location of c++ dll.  When you compile the c# dll will be automatically copied to the bin folder of the c# project.

Comment: @jdweng thank you, this is exactly what I looking for, I also marked it "copy always" in "Copy to output directory" property

Comment: Note that this will always select the same dll, even if you switch build (eg. from debug to release).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make the C++ project a dependency of the C# project. This ensures that the C++ project will be built before the C# project if it's outdated. You can set the project dependencies in the **solution** settings.

Now that we ensured that the dll is always up to date, we have to somehow get it in the same directoy as the C# executable. We have two options:

1. a post build command to copy the dll to the output directory of the C# project, or
2. we set the output directory of both projects to the same directory.

### Post build event

We can simply use a copy command. Go to *C++ project settings > Build Events > Post-Build Event* and copy the following command to to the *Command Line* field:

```
xcopy /y "$(OutDir)*.dll" "$(SolutionDir)MY_CSHARP_PROJECT_NAME\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)"
```

Replace `MY_CSHARP_PROJECT_NAME` with the name of your C# project. I'm using the default paths here, depending on your solution you might have to tweak the paths a bit.

### Shared build directory

I wouldn't recommend this one, because you can run into trouble with it.

1. Go to the *Build* tab in the project settings of your C# project.
2. At the top of the page select *Debug* as configuration.
3. At the bottom of the page change *Output path* to match the C++ output directory for *Debug* builds (this one is usually in the same folder as the solution file).
4. Repeat 2 and 3 but this time with *Release* instead of *Debug*.

Comment: very good explanation, still in my case add the dll as existing item was more suitable solution